# Else If Statement For Text version of Month from Numerical Version of Month

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to take the Numerical version of a month that i get from &_POST["finalmonth"] and convert it to the text version of the month. For example: 01 = January.

When I use an if statement:

```
 if ($_POST["finalmonth"]=01){
    $textmonth="January";
    }
 echo $textmonth;
```

It works just fine. However, I need this to work for all months so I tried and if elseif statement to no avail:

```
    if ($_POST["finalmonth"]=01){
    $textmonth="January";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=02){
    $textmonth="February";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=03){
    $textmonth="March";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=04){
    $textmonth="April";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=05){
    $textmonth="May";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=06){
    $textmonth="June";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=07){
    $textmonth="July";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=08){
    $textmonth="August";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=09){
    $textmonth="September";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=10){
    $textmonth="October";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=11){
    $textmonth="November";
    } elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]=12){
    $textmonth="December";
    }
```

echo $textmonth; only returns a value of 1 and nothing else.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE: Thanks to all who helped. I have tried both geoandri's switch method which works fine and I will probably use an array as Cheery has stated. Thanks again.

Comment: check switch statement. Less  complicated.Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: You have so many problems here.. Did you, by chance, opened any textbook about php at least once? Condition uses only `==`, not `=`. `05` is `5`, but what you get from the form is always a string, so the quotes are needed. You do not need `if .. then` here, simple associative array will solve all the problems.

Comment: @geoandri Thanks. That should help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$names = array(
 '01' => 'January',
 '02' => 'February',
 '03' => 'March',
 '04' => 'April',
 '05' => 'May',
 '06' => 'June',
 '07' => 'July',
 '08' => 'August',
 '09' => 'September',
 '10' => 'October',
 '11' => 'November',
 '12' => 'December'
);

if (!isset($names[$_POST["finalmonth"]]))
  echo 'Unknown month';
else
  echo $names[$_POST["finalmonth"]];
```

As I wrote in comments, `=` is an assignment, logical comparison is `==`. Also you are getting string from the form, not integers. Array is given just to show the idea, it can be used for many other purposes.

ps: the code above assumes, as shown in your example, that you are actually sending from form `01`, `02` and so on. If you submit `1`, `2` keys should be modified correspondingly or removed at all as numerical array starts from 0 to 11 and you can send corresponding indexes from the form.

Comment: This will fail. $_POST["finalmonth"] will be treated as an integer and thus 03 would evaluate to 3 which is not found in your array.

Comment: @Ali `will be treated as an integer` you never get integers from the form, only strings. And if he sends `03`, as listed in his example, it will work - I do not know what he actually sends from the form.

Comment: Thanks @Cheery It works fine. I know that arrays are PHP 101 but I as I didn't hardly ever need them until now, I never messed with them. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelWhite This method is useful if you want to use your own names for months and anything else. If the system names are fine, the one liner examples with `date` are better, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array containing all of the month names and use the month ID as the index in the array to reference. Also, you're using the wrong comparison operator. You want to use ==

Comment: Reading up on it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using DateTime to address such issues, it's really simply to use

```
$month = 3;
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
echo $dt->format('F'); // March
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/lQ44q)

Answer (score 1):

What you do there is assign the value to your variable and not checking.

You need to use == or === to perform validation actions - or you get into switch - case. Another approach would be variables.

Example with ==:

```
if ($_POST["finalmonth"]==01){
$textmonth="January";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==02){
$textmonth="February";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==03){
$textmonth="March";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==04){
$textmonth="April";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==05){
$textmonth="May";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==06){
$textmonth="June";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==07){
$textmonth="July";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==08){
$textmonth="August";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==09){
$textmonth="September";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==10){
$textmonth="October";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==11){
$textmonth="November";
} elseif ($_POST["finalmonth"]==12){
$textmonth="December";
}
```

I just wonder why you don't use a mix of mktime and the date functions here.

Answer (score 0):

this is kinda ugly but 
   `echo date('F',strotime("2014-$_POST[finalmonth]-01"))`

the date function return the full month name (by sending 'F') to the date that we concatenate
as i said, it's ugly but it works

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php

 if (isset($names[$_POST["finalmonth"]])){ 
 $months = array(   //create array of month
 '01' => 'January', 
'02' => 'February',
 '03' => 'March',
 '04' => 'April',
 '05' => 'May',
 '06' => 'June',
 '07' => 'July',
'08' => 'August',
 '09' => 'September',
 '10' => 'October',
 '11' => 'November',
 '12' => 'December'
); 
$numeric=$_POST["finalmonth"];

foreach($months as $key=>$month){
if($key == $numeric){
$in_numeric=$key;
$in_word=$month;
}
}
if(!empty($in_numeric) and !empty($in_word)){
print 'Month in number is '.$in_numeric; echo '<br/>';
print 'Month in Words is '.$in_word; 

} else{ print 'entered month was wrong'; }
}
?>
```